# Script lagging so much when i hold down the 'q' key/hotkey

Tags: autohotkey

I'm trying to spam 'q' in game but only if some pixels are on-screen as condition, but I'm having a problem with it being super laggy when I hold down 'q' for a long period of time to spam it. And when I release the 'q' button, the script continues to spam 'q' and 'lbutton', and the fps drops significantly in my game each time. I've tried extending the timer and using really small 1x3 pixel images for pattern matching, but it's still lagging. Can someone help me figure out why it's so laggy? If it's not the timer or the images, I'm not sure what else could be causing it. Here's the script:

```
global agilityPixelPattern := "D:\agility_pixel_pattern.png"
global chatPixelPattern := "D:\chat_pixel_pattern.png"
global consolePixelPattern := "D:\console_pixel_pattern.png"

bottomHalfHeight := A_ScreenHeight / 2
topHalfHeight := bottomHalfHeight
leftHalfWidth := A_ScreenWidth / 2
rightHalfWidth := leftHalfWidth

gameConditionsMet := gameConditionsStatus()

SetTimer, CheckConditions, 50
Return

CheckConditions:
If WinActive("ahk_exe game.exe") {
    ; Check for conditions and update the variable
    gameConditionsMet := gameConditionsStatus()
}
Return

gameConditionsStatus() {
    return !ImageSearchSuccess(chatPixelPattern, "BottomHalf") && !ImageSearchSuccess(consolePixelPattern, "EntireScreen") && ImageSearchSuccess(agilityPixelPattern, "BottomHalf")
}

ImageSearchSuccess(pattern, searchRegion := "BottomHalf") {
    if (searchRegion = "BottomHalf") {
        ImageSearch, foundX, foundY, 0, %bottomHalfHeight%, A_ScreenWidth,     A_ScreenHeight, %pattern%
    } else if (searchRegion = "EntireScreen" or "") {
        ImageSearch, foundX, foundY, 0, 0, A_ScreenWidth, A_ScreenHeight, %pattern%
    }
    return !ErrorLevel
}

#If WinActive("ahk_exe game.exe") && (gameConditionsMet)
*~$q::
    Send, q{LButton}q{LButton}q{LButton}
Return
```

Comment: `If WinActive("ahk_exe game.exe")` says nothing about the game.

Comment: @Relax I don't think the game name matters because the lag isn't coming from the game but from the script.